# How do you download and import Unity projects shared with you on Unity Collab

Tags: unity-game-engine, collaboration

I need to know how to download projects from Unity Collab shared with me.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Unity Hub
2. Proceed to Projects Panel the right side of your screen
3. Next Click the refresh Button on the button of the screen
   [image: Picture Of Screen]
4. Finally you will see all the projects that are available on your cloud(collab)[image: Picture Of Screen]
5. Now click the download icon on the project you would like to download

Answer (score 3):

For Unity Hub new versions (3.0+):

1. Open Unity Hub
2. Click to Open Arrow
   [image: Click to Open Arrow]
3. Click to "Open remote project"
4. Select your project and click "Next" *(if it doesn't show, you can try to "Refresh" button.)*
5. Choose a location and start downloading with the selected Unity version.

Comment: Assets folder is always empty for all projects that were using Unity Collab. Is there a way to download just an archive for the old project? Where Unity stores them now?